# Diablo 2 empowered summoning skills after weapon swap

Tags: diablo-ii

Say I'm playing a necromancer with a staff or a head that empowers my summoning skills (golem mastery, skeleton mastery, clay golem, etc...) and I summon a golem or a skeleton with this item equipped. Do all the skill perks stay on that summoned creature when I change my equipment (with <kbd>w</kbd>)?

Answer (score 3):

On the Diablo wiki under the [Summonmancer](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Summonmancer) (Found near the bottom of the page above the header "Gear") page it states that any bonus's applied at the time of summon will stay even if u switch gear with w. Although you will lose any bonus number of summons while switching gear.

Comment: One skeleton may die, but I'm not so sure that this retroactively affects the stats of the skeletons that remain. Do you have a source?

Comment: I am almost possitive that the stats of a summon are determined at **summon** time.  The reason a summon dies whenever you lose the necessary skill points is due to not having enough skills to sustain the summon.  The stats of a summon remain until that summon dies.  I'll go look for a good source.

Comment: @zero298 I'm under the same impression. Can't find any source though... Need some proof to confirm or deny this answer